# How to Return a value on click of a button in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="one">Try it</button>
<h1>JavaScript Functions</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", onefunction);
function onefunction(){
 //document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x;
 return 1;

 }
```

please check the above mentioned code.

//`**enter code here**`I need 1 to be returned to var x

Comment: You can't do that, and it makes no sense to do so. This is probably an X/Y problem, you're trying to do something, but you're going about it the wrong way. Why do you need `1`, what do you intend to do with that value ?

Comment: In most cases, this is not very useful. I agree with @adeneo -- It's probably an X/Y problem.

Comment: I am trying to implement a simple Calculator .SO i need to get the value of the button pressed like 1,2...9.Can u guide me?

Answer (score 1):

***Here is want you need :***

*HTML PART :*

`<button id="one" onclick="onefunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>`

*JS PART :*

`function onefunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1;
}`

> **BUT I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS WAY OF CODING**

Comment: I don't recommend it, either, since it will not work. It _only_ sets the `innerHTML` once in the very beginning, clicking the button does not change that.